# C# запись в Excel-файл. Независимость от версий Microsoft Office

Tags: c#, excel

Нужно записать данные в таблицу Excel.
Делаю вот так:

```
Excel.Application exApp = new Excel.Application();
exApp.Visible = true;
exApp.Workbooks.Add();
Worksheet workSheet = (Worksheet)exApp.ActiveSheet;
workSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "№";
workSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Имя студента";
workSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Группа";
workSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Средний балл";
int rowExcel = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < NGrants; i++)
{
    workSheet.Cells[rowExcel, "A"] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value;
    workSheet.Cells[rowExcel, "B"] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value;
    workSheet.Cells[rowExcel, "C"] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value;
    workSheet.Cells[rowExcel, "D"] = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value;
    ++rowExcel;
}

workSheet.SaveAs("MyFile.xls");`
```

На моем компьютере все работает, но на компьютере заказчика выдает unhandled exception, даже не запускает Excel. Что это? Что-то с версиями Excel связано? И как можно "малой кровью" исправить, чтоб для любой версии работало?

Comment: Использовать библиотеки на основе Office Open XML. [Epplus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/), например. В этом случае MS Office не нужен.

Comment: Office Open XML используется в 2007 и позднее, на сколько я знаю. Мне бы чтоб 2003 тоже тянул...

Comment: Чего вы с этим старьем носитесь то? Даже 2003-ий офис умеет открывать формат новых офисов (если стоит обновление "пакет обеспечения совместимости). Не вижу причин цепляться за старое.

Answer (score 1):

При создании Excel.Application() обворачиваем вызов через try...catch и выводим текст ошибки.

А для кроссплатформенности лучше писать данные не в XLS, а в CSV формат, определив разделители (например, ";") и добавить первой строкой в CSV текст "sep=;"

CSV файл откроется чем угодно, включая блокнот, это обычный текстовик. В Excel же откроется как таблица.

Как пример файла:
sep=;
a;b;vc;d;edf
d;e;f;dfg;h
v;f;dft;g;j